# Page layout issues with dynamically created controls using css

Tags: css

I have two css class that control the dynamically created controls in asp.net. What I am trying to do is properly display the dynamically created controls using the following css. I have attached my current behavior using the following css in this issue as a screenshot. I would really appreciate any help on this css issue. What I want to display is the label on the left and the textbox/dropdown on the right next to each other. Something like label: Textbox.

```
.form-control{
    width:300px;
    float:left;
    margin:10px;
}

.form-control-label{
    clear:left;
    float:left;
    width:350px;
    text-align:left;
    margin:10px;
}

.form-control-dropdown {
    float: left;
    width: 305px;
    text-align: left;
    margin: 10px;
}
```

[image: Formatting issues with dynamically created textboxes and dropdowns]

Comment: can you share the HTML too?

Comment: What is the desired look?

Comment: @Midas Label on the left and textbox/dropdown on the right next to it. Something like Label: Input

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```css
.form-control{
  width:300px;
  margin:10px;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  flex-wrap: nowrap;
  justify-content: space-between; 
}

.form-control label{
  flex-basis: 50%;
  flex-shrink: 0;
}

.form-control input, .form-control select{
  flex-basis: 50%;
  flex-shrink: 0;
}
```

```html
<form>
  <div class="form-control">
    <label>Select an End of the Month Date:</label>
    <input type="text">
  </div>
  <div class="form-control">
    <label>State:</label>
    <select></select>
  </div>
  <div class="form-control">
    <label>Agency List:</label>
    <select></select>
  </div>
  <div class="form-control">
    <label>Company:</label>
    <select></select>
  </div>
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

Wrap your labels and controls in `p` elements as seen here:
[How to structure an HTML form](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/HTML/Forms/How_to_structure_an_HTML_form)

```html
<form>
  <p>
    <label>Select an End of the Month Date: <input type="text"></label>
  </p>
  <p>
    <label>State: <input type="text"></label>
  </p>
  <p>
    <label>Agency List: <input type="text"></label>
  </p>
  <p>
    <label>Company: <input type="text"></label>
  </p>
</form>
```